# JSP Spring MVC Populating Form Fields Based on Value in Another Field

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC Form that I am building in a JSP, which will require entering an account number in a field. When I enter that number, I want to run a query to the database to pull back related information for that specific number. This data will then populate other fields on the form.

This is my Spring bind code in the JSP for the account number that will be entered. So, as soon as I enter this number, a DB query should trigger, to bring back the data for the other fields.

```
<spring:bind path="strExpenseAcctNum">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Expense Account Number :</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <form:input path="strExpenseAcctNum" type="string" class="form-control " id="strExpenseAcctNum" placeholder="strExpenseAcctNum" />
            <form:errors path="strExpenseAcctNum" class="control-label" />
        </div>
    </div>
</spring:bind>
```

From my research, I am thinking a combination of Javascript and JQuery might be the best approach, but being new at this, I am not sure how to configure it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Start by learning about binding events to elements.  http://learn.jquery.com/events/ followed by learning about ajax.  http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/  The idea being to bind an event to capture when input is entered into your text field, and when you want to, shoot off an ajax request to an endpoint you have with the data, which will return a response with which you will update your page in some manner.

Comment: Thank you Taplar

Answer (score 0):

@Dave

First implement your form using spring form tags, something like below.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/spring-mvc-example" modelAttribute="example">
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="number">Account Number</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="number" id="number"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Then use Jquery's focusout method to make an Ajax call in the background as soon as the user focus outs from account number field. Then in the success block, just parse it if needed and bind to your other fields using jquery's val method like below.

```
$("#number").focusout(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"https://example.com/getDetails",
         success: function(data) {
             //Response from the controller comes here
             var json = JSON.stringify(data);
             //Bind it to fields like these
             $("#firstname").val(json.firstname);
         }
      });
});
```

Hope this works for you, let me know if any questions.